# Merging two directory without copying the files

Tags: command-line, directory, cp

Let's say I have as follows :

```
Folder A
    C1
        file a
    A2

Folder B
     C1
     B2
         file b
     B3
```

What I want is to merge these two folders, which would give me :

```
Folder C
    C1
    A2
    B2
    B3
```

Notice I didn't write `file a` and `file b`. I only want to merge the architecture. Each repository contains different files and I don't want them to be added to the merged directory. As a consequence, `mv Folder\ A/* Folder\ B` is not adequate.

Do you guys see a way to do so ?

Comment: so you basically want to copy the directories but not the files in the directories?

Comment: That's exactly my need.

Comment: all right, here's my lazy answer: `mkdir dir3 && cp -r dir1/* dir3/ && cp -r dir2/* dir3/`, then use `find` to go through and find any regular files and delete them.

Comment: @strugee; Expensive. Use cp -rl to hardlink, then it's cheaper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you could have `find` exec `mkdir`.

```
cd /A/
find -type d -exec mkdir -p /C/{} \;
```

Or if the structure is flat as shown in your example, without `find`

```
cd /A/
for dir in */
do
    mkdir -p /C/"$dir"
done
```

and in both cases the same again for `cd /B/`.

Comment: I tried your first solution (structure is not flat), but I'm affraid I can't find the folder C. Where is it supposed to go ?

Comment: @fxm: He's just abbreviating your folder names. Where he says `A`, he means the same thing you named as `Folder A`. So, `C` is `Folder C`. File names with spaces in them require careful attention to quoting, so it's simpler to give a correct example this way.

Comment: Also note it needs either absolute paths or paths relative to `/A/` or `/B/`, e.g. `../C/` instead of `C/`. I assumed A B C was an example and you know how to specify the location of the real directories.

Comment: I realize it, but changing `/C/` by `~/newFolder/` doesn't seems to create the afroementionned folder in my home

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. Use \; instead of +.

Comment: I was affraid I didn't even understand this part of the command :] It works now, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to create the same directory structure, you can call `find` to traverse each existing directory tree and call `mkdir` with the right argument on each subdirectory. Call `mkdir -p` to silently skip directories that already exist.

```
cd 'Folder A'
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p '/path/to/Folder C/{} '\;
cd 'Folder B'
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p '/path/to/Folder C/{} '\;
```

In zsh, assuming that `Folder A`, `Folder B` and `Folder C` are subdirectories of the same directory:

```
mkdir -p Folder\ [AB]/**/*(/e\''REPLY=Folder\ C/${REPLY#*/}'\')
```

If you want to reproduce the directory hierarchy with file permissions, you can call rsync, and give it a filter that only includes the directories and not the regular files. Make sure to include a `/` at the end of the source directories so that their content is copied directly under `/path/to/Folder C` without creating `/path/to/Folder C/path/to/Folder A` and so on.

```
rsync -a --include='*/' --exclude='*' '/path/to/Folder A/' '/path/to/Folder B/' '/path/to/Folder C'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
$ (find "Folder A"/* -type d ; find "Folder B"/* -type d) | \
           sed 's#[^/]\+/##' | xargs -I{} mkdir -p "Folder C"/{}
```

#### Details

This will generate the list of sub-directories under "Folder A" and Folder B", that list will look like this:

```
Folder A/A2
Folder A/C1
Folder B/B2
Folder B/B3
Folder B/C1
```

Piping that output through this `sed` command will remove the "Folder .." bit:

```
sed 's#[^/]\+/##'
```

Resulting in this:

```
A2
C1
B2
B3
C1
```

**NOTE:** The above `sed` is looking from the left side, finding everything that is not a slash, up to the first slash, these characters are then substituted with nothing, essentially deleting them.

At this point you just need to `mkdir` under the "Folder C" directory, so we'll use `xargs` to do this repetitive task:

```
xargs -I{} mkdir -p "Folder C"/{}
```

This says to take each argument in as `{}` and substitute it into the following command ever where there's a corresponding `{}`.

#### Example

Sample data:

```
$ tree Folder\ {A,B,C}
Folder A
|-- A2
`-- C1
    `-- filea
Folder B
|-- B2
|   `-- fileb
|-- B3
`-- C1
Folder C
```

**NOTE:** See "Folder C" is empty to start.

Now we run our command:

```
$ (find "Folder A"/* -type d ; find "Folder B"/* -type d) | \
           sed 's#[^/]\+/##' | xargs -I{} mkdir -p "Folder C"/{}
```

And we're left with the following:

```
$ tree Folder\ C
Folder C
|-- A2
|-- B2
|-- B3
`-- C1
```

Comment: How about `find A/ B/ -type d -print0 | sed -z ... | xargs -0 ...`?